# Unknown provider $ocLazyLoad when using with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

I am trying to use `$ocLazyLoad` inside of Angular.js with TypeScript. However I keep getting a [Unknown provider error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=cis&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider:%20$ocLazyLoad%0Ahttp:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524ocLazyLoad%0A%20%20%20%20at%20REGEX_STRING_REGEXP%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:68:12)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:4262:19%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:4409:39)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:4441:13)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:4356:35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:4365:11%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:336:20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:4346:5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:4272:11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js:1630:20). I am including it in my primary app:

## index.module.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../.tmp/typings/tsd.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="index.route.ts" />
/// <reference path="index.config.ts" />
/// <reference path="index.run.ts" />

module myApp {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'oc.lazyLoad'])
    .config(RouterConfig)
    .config(Config)
    .run(RunBlock);
}
```

The error come from when I try to include it in my `RouterConfig`:

## index.route.ts

```
module myApp {
  'use strict';

  export class RouterConfig {

    static $inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$ocLazyLoad'];

    constructor($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoad: oc.ILazyLoad) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

      $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
          url: '/dashboard',
          templateUrl: 'app/modules/core/dashboard/dashboard.html'
        });
    }

  }
}
```

The really strange part is that I can include `$ocLazyLoadProvider` without any problems. This is a very bare-bones setup from [Yeoman using gulp, typescript, and ui-router](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in `.config(RouterConfig)`.

The *function* passed into `config` is not called with the `new` operator, Therefore *don't use a typescript `class`* here.

Comment: Are you sure? `RouterConfig` works great when I don't include `$ocLazyLoad`. Also, this is a class that is generated by the [Yeoman generator](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) - I did not create it.

Comment: @lightswitch05 yes. You will get an issue as soon as you think you can use `this`